# Spring MVC 5.3 URL Parsing URI Template Variable Problem

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-batch-admin

I am working with the old Spring Batch Admin project (I know it is no longer supported). I have it working with Spring framework 5.1. I recently upgraded to 5.3.4 and started seeing problems. Spring Batch Admin uses freemarker templates to generate html, json, or rss. Users determine the output by adding an extension to the URL (for example ".json" or ".rss"). The default with no extension is for the html rendering.

The URL parsing changes that is part of 5.3 (https://spring.io/blog/2020/06/30/url-matching-with-pathpattern-in-spring-mvc) is causing problems. It matches /job/execution/1.json with the right URL /job/execution/{jobid} but the URL template variable is jobid=1.json instead of jobid=1. This causes a problem with the method invocation because it is trying to match a long variable with the string "1.json".

I realize that adding an extension to a URL is not the current approach to returning different results with content types. Anyone have an recommendation for a path forward?

Comment: Do you need the json response or just html?  If just html you could try https://github.com/httpants/spring-batch-admin

Answer (score 0):

The issue and solution are discussed here. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26119